I can't connect and run spring boot + postgre in docker (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.)
This is my dockerfile
#download the openjdk image
FROM openjdk:17

# add argument to the docker image
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} api-service.jar

# run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","api-service.jar"]

# expose the port
EXPOSE 8080

And this is my docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  spring-boot-postgres-crud:
    container_name: spring-boot-postgres-crud
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1505
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/ems
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=1505
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1505
      - POSTGRES_DB=ems
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

And this is my applications.properties
spring.application.name=CRUD_SpringBoot_PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/ems
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1505
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.diaplect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

and this is my applycations.yml
server:
  port: 80
spring:
  application:
    name: CRUD_SpringBoot_PostgreSQL
  profiles:
    #    active: dev
    active: @spring.profiles.active@


I used maven command "mvn clean package -DskipTests -P dev" and it can build the jar file.
I used maven command "mvn clean package -P dev" and it can not build the jar file and have error.
then I use command "docker-compose up -d spring-boot-postgres-crud" it have error
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

docker-compose up -d spring-boot-postgres-crud will only start spring-boot-postgres-crud - how should it connect to DB if only SpringBoot was started? docker-compose up -d would start all services in docker-compose.yml. Also paste the errors into the question (correctly formatted)
